# pandas Series.index behaviour not allowing to reassign index in a single-line operation

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I am calculating means of columns and I want to rename the columns appending the string `_avg`.

Following the example in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108082/1714692) works: so if I do:

```
ss = df[col_list].mean()
ss.index = [el+"_avg" for el in col_list]
```

But although `df[col_list].mean()` is a `pandas.Series` type doing:

```
ss = df[col_list].mean().index = [el+"_avg" for el in col_list]
```

returns a list of strings and

```
ss = pandas.Series(df[col_list].mean().index = [el+"_avg" for el in col_list])
```

is not working at all while as in the previous link

```
ss = pandas.Series(df[col_list].mean(), index= [el+"_avg" for el in col_list])
```

changes the names but the values become `NaN`. (This behaviour is actually explained in the doc)

Why is that and how can I merge the two expressions a single line?

Comment: `x = y.index = z` does `x = z` and then `y.index = x`. It doesn't do `x = y` and then `y.index = z`.

Comment: C.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601823/how-do-chained-assignments-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498441/what-is-this-kind-of-assignment-in-python-called-a-b-true.

Comment: Actually I am doing  `x = new_type(y.index=z)` am I not?

Comment: Nope. Assignment chaining is kinda funny. Using multiple lines for multiple simple assignments is generally clearer and easier to read for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`add_suffix` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add_suffix.html):

```
ss = df[col_list].mean().add_suffix('_avg')
```

---

For example,

```
In [75]: ss = pd.Series([1,2,3], list('ABC'))

In [76]: ss.add_suffix('_avg')
Out[76]: 
A_avg    1
B_avg    2
C_avg    3
dtype: int64
```

There is also an [`add_prefix` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add_prefix.html):

```
In [77]: ss.add_prefix('col_')
Out[77]: 
col_A    1
col_B    2
col_C    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to extract the `values` from the series?

```
ss = pandas.Series(df[col_list].mean().values, index= [el+"_avg" for el in col_list])
```