# Using reindex within function is only producing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, reindex

Simple example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1900, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1903, 1903, 1905]
})
```

I have the below function that takes in a pandas dataframe:

```
def my_function(df):
    df = df.groupby(['year']) # group the df by year
    new_df = pd.DataFrame() # make a new empty df
    new_df['frequency'] = df['year'].count() # get frequency counts for each year
    return new_df
```

However, the output for this doesn't give me a `0` frequency count for the missing years.

Ideal output of my_function(df):

```
year frequency
1900 1
1901 3
1902 1
1903 3
1904 0
1905 1
```

```
Current output of my_function(df):
1900 1
1901 3
1902 1
1903 3
1905 1
```

I think I'm close with pd.reindex() but need some direction.

I've scanned the [docs for pd.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and tried looking at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108046/python-reindex-producing-nan) and I still haven't been able to solve it.

I've defined a range of ideal years in  a new variable

`new_idx = range(1900, 1905)`

And then tried implementing `pd.reindex()` like so:
`new_df.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0)`

This resulted in a slightly different function that now looks like this:

```
def my_function(df):
    new_idx = range(1900, 1905)
    df = df.groupby(['year'])
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df['frequency'] = df['year'].count()
    new_df = new_df.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0)
    return new_df
```

However, this results in a new pd.dataframe() that is the size that I'd like (length of the years in new_idx) but it overrides all frequency values to be 0 instead of just the "added" years.

Ideal output of slightly tweaked `my_function(df)`:

```
year frequency
1900 1
1901 3
1902 1
1903 3
1904 0
1905 1
```

Current output of slightly tweaked `my_function(df)`:

```
year frequency
1900 0
1901 0
1902 0
1903 0
1904 0
1905 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you want [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)

```
new_df=( df['year'].value_counts()
                   .reindex(range(df['year'].min(),df['year'].max()+1),fill_value=0)
                   .rename_axis('year')
                   .reset_index(name='frecuency')
                    )
print(new_df)
```

---

```
       year  frecuency
0  1900          1
1  1901          3
2  1902          1
3  1903          3
4  1904          0
5  1905          1
```

Comment: This looks really close, and works on the small dataset given. However, I would ideally be able to apply this to dataframes of varying length as the years might be missing at the beginning or the end of the range. So instead of setting the range to be the min() and max() of the df argument, I'd like it to be say, of range(1986, 2019). However, this seems to result in the same error in the original post (i.e. all frequencies are replaced with 0s). Any ideas?

Comment: It could be due to the type of the . Are you using str float or int?

Comment: I am using type int. For me if I use the test df posted then I get all zeros in the 'year' Series when trying to expand the index by a larger range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) + [pd.Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1900, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1903, 1903, 1905]
})

# generate date range between minimum and maximum year, with yearly frequency
range = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(df.min(), 1, 1), end=pd.datetime(df.max(), 1, 1), freq='AS')

# fill each year with the corresponding count set missing to zero
result = pd.Series(range.year, index=range.year).map(df.year.value_counts()).fillna(0)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
1900    1.0
1901    3.0
1902    1.0
1903    3.0
1904    0.0
1905    1.0
dtype: float64
```

The idea is to generate a yearly date range between the first and the last year and map the frequencies of the years to the this range.