# Reindex causing NaN values when trying to sort data frame by Month

Tags: python, reindex

I'm trying to reindex my data frame so it shows the months in order from January to December but for a reason I don't understand the data frame is replaced with NaN values when reindexed.

```
# sets 'Date' column as a datetime object to be processed in the plot.
df_discharge['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_discharge['Date']) 

# creates month column
df_discharge['Month'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_discharge['Date']).dt.strftime('%B')

# index which orders the months correctly
new_index = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
             'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

# reindexs with list of months in order
df_discharge = df_discharge.reindex(new_index).reset_index()

df_discharge
```

Comment: It is good to write some content of the original `df_discharge` by 'df_discharge.head()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108046/python-reindex-producing-nan